# Stop CircularProgressIndicator when error occurs

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I built a login page using firebase. When the user clicks the login button, a CircularProgressIndicator is started and if the user gave the correct credentials everything works perfectly but if there is an error (e.g user not found OR wrong password) the user will be not forwarded to the next page but the CircularProgressIndicator will not stop showing.

The aim is, that if there is an error, I want to stop the CircularProgressIndicator and want to show an error message but I don't know how to stop the CircularProgressIndicator.

My code looks the following:

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

class LoginUser {

  Future loginUser(userEmail, userPassword, context) async {
    navigatorKey: navigatorKey;

    showDialog(
      barrierDismissible: false,
      context: context,
      builder: (context) => Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
    );


    try {
      await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: userEmail,
          password: userPassword
      );
      // Close Dialog when route changes

    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      if (e.code == 'user-not-found') {
        return "ec-unf";
      } else if (e.code == 'wrong-password') {
        return "ec-wp";
      }

      navigatorKey.currentState!.popUntil((route) => route.isFirst);
    }
  }
}

Does anybody know how to do this?

Thanks!
Chris
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

maybe you can add isLoading and finaly condition after try catch

```
isLoading = true
try {
  //your code
  print("done !"); 
  isLoading
} catch (err) {
  print("error");
  isLoading = false
} finally {
  print("Finish "); //error and success
  isLoading = false
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I used this solution but I had to move the function from a separated file into the main login page, then it worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness, here is how i solved it.

I created a separate function in the login file and when i clicked the Sign in buttton, the following function was executed:

```
Future login() async{
    isSignInLoading = true; // START LOADING CYCLE

    // --- LOADING CYCLE - START ---
    if (isSignInLoading == true) {
      showDialog(
          barrierDismissible: false,
          context: context,
          builder: (context) => Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
      );
    }
    // --- LOADING CYCLE - END ---

    try {
      await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: _controllerEmail.text,
          password: _controllerPassword.text
      );

    } catch (e) {
      isSignInLoading = false; // START LOADING CYCLE
      isErrorLogin = true; // START LOADING CYCLE
    }
    Navigator.of(context).pop();

    // --- ERROR MESSAGE - START ---
    if (isErrorLogin == true) {
      showDialog(
          barrierDismissible: false,
          context: context,
          builder: (context) => Center(child:
            AlertDialog(
              title: const Text('Something went wrong!'),
              content: const  Text('Please check your entries, either the user does not exist or the password is incorrect.'),
              actions: [
                TextButton(
                    child: const Text(
                        'Close',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Color(0xff004494),
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500
                      ),
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                    },
                ),
              ],
            )
          )
      );
    }
    // --- ERROR MESSAGE - END ---

    //var loginInfo = await LoginUser().loginUser(_controllerEmail.text,_controllerPassword.text, context);
    if (FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser != null) {
      SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      prefs.setBool("userLoginStatus", true);
      Navigator.popAndPushNamed(context, '/overview');
    }
  }
```

Pretty sure there is a way better way to do it but this worked for me.